# web framework/CMS fingerprinting?

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

Is there a piece of software out there that can tell me what framework or CMS was used to build a particular site? I'm thinking there might be something that can look at the way a page is formatted and deduce what, if any, framework or CMS was used to generate it.

Comment: That would be a difficult guess, as most modern CMS' provide a way to fully personalize the used templates. Even file structures can differ from installation to installation. The only system you will recognize for sure is Wordpress, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doubtful you'll find a tool that can identify the CMS behind *any* site, if only because it's possible to hide most of them if you're determined enough and some even make it easy.

[Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com/) can be installed as a plugin for Firefox or Safari, and also offers a bookmarklet version at bottom of the install page.

[BuiltWith](http://builtwith.com/) runs as a web service and provides a lot of information like Javascript libraries used, advertising managers, etc. including some CMS apps.

There's a Windows application called CyberMake that seems primarily intended for keyword research which claims it can identify an extensive list of applications. But it seems sketchy to me for several reasons you can figure out yourself if you decide to search for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Chrome Sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae) works perfectly and identifies almost every CMS and JavaScript Frameworks and other plugins like Piwik etc.